# How should i deal with a type error, int() argument must be a string or a number?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `OrderItem`,

```
class OrderItem(SmartModel):
    shopping_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

and i am doing this in my function to create an object,

```
try:
   order= Order.objects.get(pk=id)
   restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
except:
   order = Order(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)

oi=OrderItem(order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                           quantity=quantity,
                           item=i,
                           created_by=anon_user,
                           modified_by=anon_user)
oi.save()
```

I am getting an error `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Order'`.
How should i go about this..

Comment: you should also only catch DoesNotExist -> except:Order.DoesNotExist, Restaurant.DoesNotExist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see various problems with your code. Firstly you're using the same `id` to get your restaurant as you are to get your order -

```
   order= Order.objects.get(pk=id)
   restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Secondly you'll need to save the order before you can pass it as a foreign key to the order item. Otherwise there won't be a primary key created on your order, so `OrderItem` will be unable to use it in the ForeignKey field.

Lastly, when you initialize your `OrderItem` you're passing order as an arg rather than a kwarg.

Your code should look something like -

```
# get order_id and restaurant_id
try:
   order= Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
   restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=restaurant_id)
except:
   order = Order(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)
   order.save()
oi=OrderItem(order=order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
             quantity=quantity,
             item=i,
             created_by=anon_user,
             modified_by=anon_user)
oi.save()
```

As an aside, you might be able to substitue your try / except statement for django's [get_or_create](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) shortcut function.

Comment: am sorry i didnt get back to these earlier.. but it worked and am grateful..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be link this.

```
oi=OrderItem.objects.create( shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                           quantity=quantity,
                           item=i,
                           order=order,
                           created_by=anon_user,
                           modified_by=anon_user)
```

Comment: you know, the foreign key `Order` does not exist, so i ave to create and in thats what am trying to achieve all in all

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a manager to create the objects properly, instantiating the class the way you do doesn't actually hit the database. `Order.objects.create(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This line -

```
order = Order(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)
```

creates an instance of the `Order` class, but is not saved to the database and it doesn't have a primary key associated with it that other models can use to save relationship unless you call `order.save()`. So you must call `order.save()`. And then create the `OrderItem` like -

```
oi=OrderItem(
    order=order,
    shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
    quantity=quantity,
    item=i,
    created_by=anon_user,
    modified_by=anon_user
)
oi.save()
```

Also, make sure `i` and `anon_user` have primary key.

Comment: this is what am doing...i just only showed a few lines of code here..sorry